# How do I define a custom coordinate system?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, projection, coordinate-systems

In Java using OpenGL I could setup matrices for world coordinates like this:

```
GL.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION);
GL.glLoadIdentity();
// window size is 640x480
// viewport size is 8x6 (e.g. in meters, so you see only 8x6 meters of the world in a flash game)
GL.glOrtho(0, 8, 0, 6, -1, 1);
```

How can I do the same in ActionScript? When my tile size is 80px I want to say

```
mySprite.x = 1; // 80 pixels
mySprite.x = 2; // 160 pixels
mySprite.x = 3; // 240 pixels
```

and it should make the sprite appear 80, 160 or 240 pixels away from the left.

Are there no equivalent projection possibilities in AS3?

Answer (score 0):

Use a spark.components.Group.  This has no background or anything else like that, so even though it kind of replaces a Canvas, it doesn't really.  It's just a group of UIComponents essentially.  That being said, set the Group's x field to 79, and call the Group's addElement() function on mySprite.  Then if you set mySprite's x field to 1, that's considered to be 1 in relation to the Group, which is already 79 pixels from the left as a whole.  So 79 + 1 = 80.

```
var group:Group = new Group();
group.x = 79;
group.addElement(mySprite);
mySprite.x = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a superclass that redefines the getters and setters for x and y, then you derive each of your MovieClips from this class.